# realloc vs malloc in C

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm fairly new to C, and just now starting to venture into the realm of dynamically allocated arrays.

I think i've got mostly `malloc` down, but had some questions on `realloc`:

1. Can `realloc` be used for anything else besides adding memory space to pointers?
2. Does the size variable always have to be an `int`?
3. Would something like the below work?

   ```
   float *L = NULL;

   int task_count = 5;

   L = (float*) realloc (L, task_count * sizeof(float));
   ```

If I wanted to increase that space further (by one in this case), could I just use something like the following?

```
L = (float*) realloc (L, 1 * sizeof(float));
```

Seems deceptively simple, which tells me I'm possibly missing something.

Comment: No, `realloc` needs to be told the TOTAL size you want.  If you want to increase by 1, you need to realloc for (in your case) 6.  Also note, `realloc` can fail, so you should assign its result to a temporary pointer first, check for success, then assign that back to the source pointer.

Comment: okay, so morale of the story, i use malloc to create the initial block of size i, then i can just use realloc, but need to specific i + whatever size increase i need?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the failure part. Didn't quite grasp why they were assigning another pointer in the [cpp reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/). Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You can pass a NULL to realloc and have it behave like `malloc`...

Comment: @user3287789 The initial allocation may be `float *L = NULL;` or `float *L = malloc(sizeof *L);` or `float *L = calloc(1, sizeof *L);` or `float *L = realloc(NULL, sizeof *L);` or ...

Answer (score 2):

In case that ptr is a null pointer, the function behaves like malloc, assigning a new block of size bytes and returning a pointer to its beginning.

```
void * realloc (void* ptr, size_t size);
```

ptr - Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or **realloc**.
      **Alternatively, this can be a null pointer, in which case a new block is allocated (as if 
      malloc was called).**

sizeNew - size for the memory block, in bytes. size_t is an unsigned integral type.

sizeNew has to define the entirety of the memory you want, could be smaller, could be larger!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can also reduce memory space
2. Nah, why that? It takes void* as 1st parameter and returns void*
3. Yes, but no need to cast!

And finally, you have to tell the total memory sizeto the function.