# realloc vs memcpy in dynamic array like vector in C

Tags: c, memory, vector, data-structures, memory-leaks

I was using a data structure vector in C. Like this

```
struct intVector 
{
  int* head;

  size_t capacity;
  size_t size;
};
```

When implementing pushIntVector function, I have two options when the array's size is equal to the capacity. In that case I need to allocate larger memory and copy all the data to it and free the old allocated data. As the doc says, realloc function reallocates memory for ptr and memcpy function copies memory from A to B.

At first glance, realloc seems great for my case as I don`t have to take care of copying memory and free-ing the old one, but what if there is no such a large memory in linear mode. On the other hand, if I malloc some larger memory somewhere else I can find one and easily copy to it and free the old one. So here I cannot clear it up which to use in my case.

Comment: Malloc also needs contiguous memory, so how does that help you?

Comment: "what if there is no such a large memory in linear mode." If `realloc` fails because of that then what makes you think `malloc` will not also fail?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428974/7852589) and [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131381/realloc-vs-malloc-in-c?rq=1) seem relevant

Comment: If you find my explanation answered your question, you can accept it as the right answer by clicking the check-mark next to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Especially when dealing with memory it is important to read the documentation very carefully. In plain terms, realloc can behave in three ways when requesting more memory than is currently allocated:

- Expanding the allocated area while leaving the original contents intact
- Allocating a new memory block and copying the existing data
- Failing (usually, but not always, due to an out-of-memory error)

The two non-error outcomes both leave the memory containing the original data and will never require a memcpy. So in this case you definitely should use realloc without any memcpy. If you hit the failure case with realloc, you will hit the failure case with malloc. Good practice is to check the return of all memory management functions and upon failure free all program resources and exit gracefully.